# While loop output

Tags: java, loops, random, while-loop, counter

The program will generate the correct output for the first number guess but after the user inputs the second guess, there is no output at all. Please help! THANKS

```
    final int number = (int)((Math.random()*99)+1);
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
    while (keyboard.nextInt() > number) {
        System.out.println("Your guess was too high. Try again.");
        counter++;
        System.out.print("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
    }
    while (keyboard.nextInt() < number) {
        System.out.println("Your guess was too low. Try again.");
        counter++;
        System.out.print("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
    }
    while (keyboard.nextInt() == number) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! Your guess was correct!");
        counter++;
        System.out.println("I had chosen " + number + " as the target number.");
        System.out.println("You guessed it in " + counter + " tries.");
        if (counter == 1) {
            System.out.println("That was lucky!");
        }
        if (counter >= 2 || counter <= 4) {
            System.out.println("That was amazing!");
        }
        if (counter == 5 || counter == 6) {
            System.out.println("That was good.");
        }
        if (counter == 7) {
            System.out.println("That was OK.");
        }
        if (counter == 8 || counter == 9) {
            System.out.println("That was not very good.");
        }
        if (counter >= 10) {
            System.out.println("This just isn't your game.");
        }
```

Comment: YOu have too many while loops. What is your final goal?

Comment: Why do you have 2 while loops?

Comment: Also, you're missing the beginning and end of your code

Comment: There's WAY too much going in in there. Why have 3 while loops? I'm assuming I keep guessing until I guess the number correctly? Look at what you are trying to solve, and break it down slowly, the sheer amount of looping alone is bewildering! Let it loop in one loop, checking if too high, too low or correct. Then spit out the response, and the loop will continue until correct. Then break out of the loop and carry on with any other code. Post the rest as some of those objects are not clear: i.e. keyboard

Comment: @joey.enfield even worse.... there are 3!!!

Comment: what is keyboard? a java.util.Scanner object?

Answer (score 3):

you really need to change your design pattern.

Once you fail to satisfy the conditions in 1 of those while loops, you code will never go back.

you should only have 1 `while` loop for the guessing phase.  you code should look like this

```
while(someCondition)
{  
    int num = keyboard.nextInt()
    if (num  > number) {   
        ...      
    }
    else if (num  < number) {  
        ...
    }
    else if (num  == number) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Your `while` loops should be `if` statements.
- There should be a `while` loop around (practically) all your code

You code should roughly look like:

```
while(true) {
    // prompt for input
    // read input
    // break from loop if input is the exit input, eg -1
    // check input - essentially change your whiles to ifs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This block doesn't seem to work as intended:

```
while (keyboard.nextInt() > number) {
    System.out.println("Your guess was too high. Try again.");
    counter++;
    System.out.print("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
}
while (keyboard.nextInt() < number) {
    System.out.println("Your guess was too low. Try again.");
    counter++;
    System.out.print("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
}
```

Assume the user enters -1 and then 101. You'll end up in the next loop. Thus you might want to change it to something like this:

```
boolean retry = true;
while ( retry ) {
    counter++;
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    if( n > number ) {
      System.out.println("Your guess was too high. Try again.");
    }
    else if( n < number ) {
      System.out.println("Your guess was too low. Try again.");
    }
    else {
      //number found
      retry = false;
    }

    if( retry ) {
        System.out.prnt("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in how you use the while statement.

Here you can find the correct version of your code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int number = (int) ((Math.random() * 99) + 1);
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
    int user_number;
    do {
        user_number = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (user_number > number) {
            System.out.println("Your guess was too high. Try again.");
            System.out.print("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
            counter++;
        } else if (user_number < number) {
            System.out.println("Your guess was too low. Try again.");
            System.out.print("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
            counter++;
        }
    } while (user_number != number);
    System.out.println("Congratulations! Your guess was correct!");
    counter++;
    System.out.println("I had chosen " + number + " as the target number.");
    System.out.println("You guessed it in " + counter + " tries.");
    if (counter == 1) {
        System.out.println("That was lucky!");
    }
    if ((counter >= 2) || (counter <= 4)) {
        System.out.println("That was amazing!");
    }
    if ((counter == 5) || (counter == 6)) {
        System.out.println("That was good.");
    }
    if (counter == 7) {
        System.out.println("That was OK.");
    }
    if ((counter == 8) || (counter == 9)) {
        System.out.println("That was not very good.");
    }
    if (counter >= 10) {
        System.out.println("This just isn't your game.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(someCondition)
{

    if (keyboard.nextInt() > number) {

        ...

    } else if(keyboard.nextInt() < number) {

        ...

    } else {

        ...

    }
```

}